# Change the datein a QDateEdit widget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

How to change the date in a QDateEdit when I press a button.

I have tried with setDate....   but doesent work

```
def loadpac(self):
    bazadate = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM caz')
    for row in bazadate:
        if row[0] == int(self.linenr.text()):
            self.date.setDate(QtCore.QDate(int(row[1][6:]), int(row[1][3:5]), int(row[1][0:2])))
```

this is not code just explain what row[1] is

row[1] = 20.03.2019

Comment: Sorry guys about this post no help needed found the problem

Answer (score 2):

```
bazadate = [
#    row[0]    row[1]      row[n]
    [ 42,     '23/02/2019',  ...    ],                #  <---  row       
    ...
]

QtCore.QDate(int(row[1][6:]), int(row[1][3:5]), int(row[1][0:2]))
QtCore.QDate(          2019 ,             2,                23)
```

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyForm(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self)
        self.dateEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2019, 2, 23), 
                                  QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
        self.dateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate(2019, 2, 23))
        self.dateEdit.setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText("{}".format(self.dateEdit.dateTime().toString('dd-MM-yyyy')))

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show selected date.')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Select a date:"), 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.dateEdit, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 2, 0, 1, 2)

    def onClick(self):
        firstDayText = '{}-01-01'.format(self.dateEdit.dateTime().toString('yyyy'))
        firstDay = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(firstDayText, "yyyy-MM-dd")
        numDay = firstDay.daysTo(self.dateEdit.dateTime())
        self.label.setText("Selected date {}, {} days have passed since the beginning of the year"
            "".format(self.dateEdit.dateTime().toString('dd-MM-yyyy'), numDay))


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]